# Is using Java assertions appropriate for verifying JPA implementation

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, assert

I'm working on an application with an (almost) vanilla Java EE 6 stack (EJB, JPA, JSF, etc.). We are hosting our application on Glassfish 3 and our persistence-related code is 100% pure JPA for now.

Unfortunately, one part of our application must use a stored procedure in an Oracle 10g database. To call this stored procedure, we've decided to use EclipseLink (the JPA implementation which is bundled with Glassfish).

As a (small) part of our code is now dependent on EclipseLink I wondered how to verify this dependency. The dependency isn't packaged with the application but it is assumed to be available on our deployment platform (i.e. Glassfish).

In my mind, our options are:

1. Don't do anything, just let it fail. I think this solution is sub-optimal as it's never made explicit that our code assumes the presence of EclipseLink.
2. Check for EclipseLink in an if-statement and throw a specific exception.

   ```java
   if (!JpaHelper.isEclipseLink(entityManager)) {
       throw new InvalidJpaImplementationException();
   }
   ```
3. Add an assertion which checks for EclipseLink and let it throw an exception if it fails.

   ```java
   assert JpaHelper.isEclipseLink(entityManager)) : "Blah!";
   ```

**Would an assertion (option 3) be a valid solution? Would you prefer another solution? Which one, and why?**

Comment: Why your stored procedure is dependent on EclipseLink? Couldn't you find a portable implementation? Show us some code...

Comment: JPA doesn't support calling stored procedures. How would you suggest we could make this more portable? It is possible to deploy EclipseLink on other application servers so I just want to make this dependency explicit in the code (besides mentioning it in documentation).

Comment: JPA 2.1 will support stored procedures (when final), and DataNucleus JPA already provides this mechanism (matching the spec). Obviously you could write your own variant like that for now and swap it out to the JPA2.1 mechanism when available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using JPA, I would not make the implementation EclipseLink specific (as it **must** conform to the JPA specification). One shouldn't care what JPA providers they're using.

Your code could break if you decide moving to (let's say) Hibernate (if you implement dependency verification). The whole purpose of the JPA specification is that the developer should never worry about the implementation vendor product at all.

---

If you want to use Eclipse Link's Stored Procedure, then I would suggest that you create an engine that would call a Stored Procedure, irrespective of the `EntityManager`. That way, it would still not worry about JPA implementation provider dependency whatsoever. An example of how to call StoredProcedure with Hibernate JPA can be found [here](http://objectopia.com/2009/06/26/calling-stored-procedures-in-jpa/).

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your comment, however, JPA doesn't provide a means to call stored procedures. These stored procedures are necessary (at the very least in the short term) but are only a small part of our application. The only solution which neatly integrates with the rest of our application (persistence-wise) is using specific features of our JPA implementation. The actual question being, _if_ we use these features, would using assertions be _appropriate_ here?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your answer. Maybe some more information: The reason I need an implementation-specific `EntityManager` is that I need the active `Session` to neatly integrate with transactions etc. This piece of code is already neatly separated from the rest of the application (which I assume is what you mean with _engine_).

Comment: My point is that you don't want to make it implementation-specific. Rather have like `EclipseLinkJPAStoredProcEngine`, which inherits `JPAStoredProcEngine` and returns whatever value you want from the store proc. That way, if you happen to move to Hibernate (E.g.) then your implementation won't break.

Comment: Unless I provide an implementation of `JPAStoredProcEngine` it still breaks though. I already separated this piece of the application from the rest but adding an interface would be a bit cleaner, true. It still doesn't answer my original question however. Within this implementation I was wondering how to check/verify/make explicit the fact that it is dependent on it.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, even though it doesn't fully answer my original question (proper use of assertions) it did lead me to a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assertions can be disabled, which would break your code on error. Hence officially better no assert. Should in the future the other entity manager become removed, you still better remove the test instead of disabling the assert. Reason: you were in "luck" that the other JPA used another implementation. Maybe logging just for InvalidJpaImplementationException is simpler too.

Comment: I know the assertions can be disabled, which is partly why I like the solution. The test isn't needlessly executed but it does make the dependency explicit. A logging statement also does this but is probably more verbose.

I'm not yet convinced of this alternative but thanks for the suggestion, I'll think about it some more.

Comment: In general I am very late removing error logging / understandable error detection from the DB layer. The gain in speed does not outweight QA - in general. But you would receive a fail fast soon enough without test. So it is up to your discretion.